# How to make scala 2.12.11 code run in scala 2.13.2?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-collections

Currently in my `BuildSettings.scala` file I am using `crossScalaVersion := Seq("2.12.11", "2.13.2")`, and my `scalaVersion := "2.13.2"`, Now when I do sbt compile, it compiles with `2.13.2` correctly without any issue. Now when I do `+ compile`, first it compiles with `2.12.11`, then with `2.13.2` and fails here. Now the reason why its failing with `2.13.2` on `+ compile` is because I have some collection libraries and  some other libraries which are supported in only `2.12.11` and not in `2.13.2`, e.g if we look at this piece of code:

```
package com.abc.models.common.implicits
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
trait TraversableExtension {
  implicit class traversableExtension[A, B](iterable: TraversableLike[A, B]) {
    def headOrError(message: String): A = {
      iterable.headOption.getOrElse(throw new Exception(message))
    }
  }
}
```

`TraversableLike` doesn't exist anymore in `2.13.2`, also in some other files I face other issues for which classes are not supported in `2.13.2` anymore.
I can update the code according to  `2.13.2` standards and support libraries, whatever is alternative to above collection etc. But then `+ compile` fails, i.e compilation with `2.12.11` fails, as those libraries won't exist in `2.12.11`.

How can I make it work with both the versions?

Comment: In addition to what Mario suggested _(which you may also need)_, for collection specific problems you should be using the [**Scala-colllection-compat** library](https://github.com/scala/scala-library-compat)

Comment: Nitpick: you seem to mean "classes", not "libraries". The only library involved here — if i understand you correctly — is the Scala standard library.

Comment: Well, I guess, collection libraries mostly: scala.collection, also some classes inside other packages like: akka-http old versions

Comment: Ah, so there are other libraries involved. Hopefully you can find versions of those dependencies that are available for both 2.12.x and 2.13.x — then you wouldn't need the tricks Mario suggests.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [Scala-version specific source directory](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Scala-version+specific+source+directory)

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── scala
│   │   ├── scala-2.12
│   │   └── scala-2.13
```

in combination with `CrossVersion.partialVersion`

```
libraryDependencies := 
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, 12)) => ???
    case Some((2, 13)) => ???
    case _ =>> ???
  }
```